# A problem about fixed point iteration theory

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

#### Description

Recently, I have been learning a couse called "**Numerical Analysis**". The `fixed point iteration theory` was introducted to solve the `the approximate root of the equations` in this course.

**Fixed point iteration theory:** $x=Ψ(x) \Rightarrow x_{k+1}=Ψ(x_k)$

#### Example

Solving the approximate root of  $f(x)=x^3+4x^2-10 = 0$

So I give three styles of $x=Ψ(x)$, shown as below:

- $Ψ_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10-x^3}$
- $Ψ_2(x)=\sqrt{\frac{10}{x+4}}$
- $Ψ_3(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=x-\frac{x^3+4x^2-10}{3x^2+8x}$

#### Using *Mathematica* to implement it and verify the results of textbook

**My trial: I set the precision to 10**

```
 result1 = FixedPointList[N[1/2 Sqrt[10 - #^3] &, 10], 1.5`10]
```

> ```
> {1.500000000, 1.286953768, 1.402540804, 1.345458374, 1.375170253, 
>    1.360094193, 1.367846968, 1.363887004, 1.365916733, 1.364878217, 
>    1.365410061, 1.365137821, 1.365277209, 1.365205850, 1.365242384, 
>    1.365223680, 1.365233256, 1.365228353, 1.365230863, 1.365229578, 
>    1.365230236, 1.365229899, 1.365230072, 1.365229984, 1.365230029, 
>    1.365230006, 1.365230017, 1.365230011, 1.365230014, 1.365230013, 
>    1.365230014}
> ```

```
  result2 = FixedPointList[N[Sqrt[10/(# + 4)] &, 10], 1.5`10]
```

> ```
> {1.500000000, 1.348399725, 1.367376372, 1.364957015, 1.365264748, 
>    1.365225594, 1.365230576, 1.365229942, 1.365230023, 1.365230012, 
>    1.365230014, 1.365230013}
> ```

```
 result3 = FixedPointList[N[# - (#^3 + 4 #^2 - 10)/(3 #^2 + 8 #) &, 10], 1.5`10]
```

> ```
>  {1.500000000, 1.373333333, 1.365262015, 1.36523001, 1.36523001}
> ```

However, the last two results of `the result3` is `1.36523001, 1.36523001`, whose precision is `9` rather than `10`

```
TableForm[
  Flatten[{result1, result2, result3}, {{2}, {1}}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, Style[#, 15, Red] & /@ {"\[Phi]1 steps", "\[Phi]2 steps", 
   "\[Phi]3 steps"}}]
```

> [image]

As the picture shown, the `result2` ia same as `the result of textbook`, however, the `result1` and `result3` are a little different from `the result of textbook`. In addition, the precison of `result3` is `9`, not `10`.

#### Question

**Can someone give me a explalation about this trial? For me, I cannot understand this result.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nice trick to force *Mathematica* to use a given precision is to use `Block` and make `$MinPrecision` equal to `$MaxPrecision`. So you can write your `result1` as:

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 10, $MaxPrecision = 10}, 
         FixedPointList[N[1/2 Sqrt[10 - #^3] &, 10], 1.5`10]]
```

> ```
> {1.500000000, 1.286953768, 1.402540804, 1.345458374, 1.375170253, 1.360094193,
>  1.367846968, 1.363887004, 1.365916733, 1.364878217, 1.365410061, 1.365137821,
>  1.365277209, 1.365205850, 1.365242384, 1.365223680, 1.365233256, 1.365228353,
>  1.365230863, 1.365229578,  1.365230236, 1.365229899, 1.365230072, 1.365229984,
>  1.365230029, 1.365230006, 1.365230017, 1.365230011, 1.365230014, 1.365230013,      
>  1.365230014, 1.365230013, 1.365230013, 1.365230013}
> ```

And similarly for `result3`

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 10, $MaxPrecision = 10}, 
     FixedPointList[N[# - (#^3 + 4 #^2 - 10)/(3 #^2 + 8 #) &, 10], 1.5`10]]
```

> ```
> {1.500000000, 1.373333333, 1.365262015, 1.365230014, 1.365230013, 1.365230013}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Mathematical operations on numbers of a given precision cannot guarantee the output to maintain the precision of the input numbers. In general precision will decrease. The amount of decrease depends on the operations and some operations will cause precision to decrease significantly. If you want a specific precision on the final result then the working precision should be higher than the desired output precision. Frequently, the working precision is done at twice the desired output precision to allow for significant lose of precision during complex calculations. In your example just using machine precision numbers will perform well.

```
result1 =
  FixedPointList[N[1/2 Sqrt[10 - #^3] &], 1.5];
{Length[result1], result1[[-1]] // InputForm}
```

> ```
> {53, InputForm[1.3652300134140969`]}
> ```

```
result2 =
  FixedPointList[N[Sqrt[10/(# + 4)] &], 1.5];
{Length[result2], result2[[-1]] // InputForm}
```

> ```
> {19, InputForm[1.3652300134140969`]}
> ```

```
result3 =
  FixedPointList[N[# - (#^3 + 4 #^2 - 10)/(3 #^2 + 8 #) &], 1.5];
{Length[result3], result3[[-1]] // InputForm}
```

> ```
> {6, InputForm[1.3652300134140969`]}
> ```

You can shorten the displayed numbers using `NumberForm`

Comment: From the explanation above you might conclude that the result of a computation always has less precision than the precision than the numbers used in the computation. However, you increase precision in the next two examples. ------- In[1]:= x=SetPrecision[6.2,4.0];
Precision[Erf[x]]   Out[2]= 19.9801   In[3]:= Precision[2+(x-62/10-10^-30)^6]  Out[3]=19.5467

Comment: @Ted Ersek - I believe that I qualified my statements: "cannot guarantee the output to maintain the precision of the input numbers" and " In general precision will decrease" so I believe none of my statements imply "always". On the other hand, I have somewhat frequently encountered situations where increased `WorkingPrecision` was required to get acceptable results.

Comment: I didn't intend to say you are wrong. However, one who does not read carefully might think precision always decreases as computation continues. I wanted to make it clear that isn't always the case.