# Calculating an integral by the Romberg Algorithm

Tags: programming, numerical-integration, algorithm

In my *"Numerical Analysis"* course, I learned the *Romberg Algorithm* to numerically calculate the integral.

The *Romberg Algorithm* as shown below:

> [image: tableau]

$$T_{2n}(f)+\frac{1}{4^1-1}[T_{2n}(f)-T_{n}(f)]=S_n(f) \\
S_{2n}(f)+\frac{1}{4^2-1}[S_{2n}(f)-S_{n}(f)]=C_n(f) \\
C_{2n}(f)+\frac{1}{4^3-1}[C_{2n}(f)-C_{n}(f)]=R_n(f)$$

where $$T_n=\frac{h}{2}\left[ f(a)+ 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i) +f(b)\right]$$ and $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$.

**My code:**

```
 trapezium[func_, n_, {a_, b_}] :=
  With[{h = (b - a)/n},
   1/2 h (func@a + 2 Sum[func[a + i h], {i, 1, n - 1}] + func@b)
 ]

rombergCalc[func_,iter_, {a_, b_}] := 
  Module[{m = 1},
   Nest[
    MovingAverage[#, {-1,4^(m++)}] &, 
    Table[trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, 0., iter}], 3]
  ]
```

**The calculation process comes from my textbook**

> [image]

**Fixed one bug 1**

> [image]

#### Update

**Fixed bug 2**

> [image]

**Test**

```
 rombergCalc[Exp, 5, {0, 1}]//InputForm
```

> ```
>  {1.7182818287945305, 1.7182818284603885, 1.7182818284590502}
> ```

#### My Question update

- In function `rombergCalc`, I utilized the usage `m++` that I believe is not suitable in *Mathematica Programming*. Is there any other method to replace `m++` or implement *Romberg Algorithm*?

<strike>- Why `Block[{$MinPrecision = precision, $MaxPrecision = precision}..]` cannot give the result that contain  `significance digit` that I gave(*seeing the graphic of textbook*)?</strike>

(Thanks for @xzczd's solution for dealing with precision problem)

```
N[{a, b}, precision]
```

and replace

```
trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, 0., iter}]
```

with

```
trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, 0, iter}]
```

<strike>- Except for `SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 16]` or `InputForm`, is there other solutions to set precision conveniently?</strike>

Comment: Have you read this ? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#618158740

Comment: I @belisarius haven't read that page. My teacher suggested us implementing that algorithm by a computer language and improve our programming ability by this practice.

Comment: I do not understand why you are dealing with Precision stuff in the implementation of this algorithm. I've implemented this also for a HW assignment but do not have time to post it now. I think you are making things much more complicated than needed with adding Precision in there.

Comment: @Nasser,This trick come from [@RunnyKine's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60282/a-problem-about-fixed-point-iteration-theory)  A nice trick to force *Mathematica* to use a given precision is to use `Block` and make `$MinPrecision` equal to `$MaxPrecision`.

Comment: I understand what this is doing. My point is that, you should first work on the algorithm to make sure it works, but eliminating any un-needed extra fancy complexity. You can always fine tune things later if needed. I'll try to look up my HW and post my code.

Comment: @Nasser, Thanks for your good suggestion:-) BTW, I'd like to know that what does `HW assignment`mean.

Comment: `what does HW assignmentmean` it means it was a home work, for school. I took a class and this was one HW.

Comment: Your results seem to match the R_n column. What is the issue with precision (your second bullet item)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau,Please see the answer of **xzczd** as below about why `Block[{$MinPrecision = precision, $MaxPrecision = precision}..]` cannot give the result that contain  significance digit:-)

Comment: I'm not surprised that @DanielLichtblau is confused. It'll be better to keep your original code in the question.

Comment: Do you mean the fact that there is no error estimate provided? Or did you have a version of code that was giving a different result?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, when I use the xzczd's solution: `N[{a,b},precison]` and replace `trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, 0., iter}] ` with `trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, 0, iter}] `, I can use my code to achieve right result. However, my code cotain `m++` that I think it is not suitable in *Mathematica*, so I update my question to discover other functional/recrusive solutions to deal with this alogrithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice to meet you, Mr. Shu.

Bug fix first. Your function doesn't work under desired precision because:

> ```
> Table[trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, **0.**, iter}]
> ```

Changing it to

```
Table[trapezium[func, 2^i, {a, b}], {i, 0, iter}]
```

still doesn't fix the problem, because all the numbers taking part in the calculation have infinite precision. Adding an

```
N[…, precision]
```

somewhere still doesn't fix the problem, because your utilization of `m++` is not only unsuitable, but also wrong. Try changing your `m++` into `(Print[i = m++]; i)` and see what will happen.

Fixed code:

```
trapezium[func_, n_, {a_, b_}] := 
 With[{h = (b - a)/n}, 
  1/2 h (func@a + 2 Sum[func[a + i h], {i, 1, n - 1}] + func@b)]

rombergCalc[func_, iter_, {a_, b_}, precision_] := 
 Block[{$MinPrecision = precision, $MaxPrecision = precision}, 
  Module[{m = 1}, 
   NestList[
    With[{n = 4^(m++)}, 
      Flatten@(MovingAverage[#, {-1, n}] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1])] &, 
    Table[trapezium[func, 2^(i - 1), N[{a, b}, precision]], {i, 
      iter}], 3]]]
```

It's so ugly now that I'd like to turn to:

```
trapezium[func_, n_, {a_, b_}] := 
 With[{h = (b - a)/n}, 
  Module[{f = Function[x, func@x, Listable]}, h (Total@f@Range[a, b, h] - 1/2 (f@a + f@b))]]

rombergCalc[func_, iter_, {a_, b_}, precision_] := 
 FoldList[Rest@# + 1/(4^#2 - 1) Differences@# &, 
  trapezium[func, 2^(# - 1), N[{a, b}, precision]] & /@ Range@iter, Range@3]
```

Finally "visualize" the result:

```
TableForm[Flatten[rombergCalc[Exp, 6, {0, 1}, 13], {{2}, {1}}], 
   TableHeadings -> {2^Range[0, 5], 
   {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(n\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(n\)]\)"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

---

For completeness, here's a compiled version of the function above. **Notice that it only speeds up `Listable` compilable internal functions or pure functions formed by `Listable` compilable internal function.**

```
trapezium[f_, n_, {a_, b_}] := 
 With[{h = (b - a)/n}, 
  h (Total[f@Range[a, b, h]] - 1/2 (f@a + f@b))]

compiledrombergCalc[f_, {a_, b_}] := 
 ReleaseHold[
  Hold@Compile[{{i, _Integer}}, 
     Fold[Rest@# + 1/(4^#2 - 1) Differences@# &, 
      trapezium[f, 2^(# - 1), {a, b}] & /@ Range@i, Range@3]] /. 
   DownValues@trapezium]

g = Exp[#] &
NumberForm[compiledrombergCalc[g, {0, 1}][18], 13] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

It's a **23X** speedup compared to the uncompiled version.

Also notice that inside the compiled function, the calculation is under `MachinePrecision` so the `Precision` of the result is also `MachinePrecision`, though its appearance is changed by `NumberForm`. However, I think this treatment may be closer to what your text book has done: as said in the comment below, [significance arithmetic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60142/1871) is the secret recipe of *Mathematica* anyway.

Comment: +1, (Seeing mu **Update**)Good solution! One of my question is that I didn't know how to deal with $$B_n=\frac{4^m}{4^m-1}A_{2n}+\frac{-1}{4^m-1}A_n$$ where, $m=1,2,3$, so I introduced the intermediate variable `m` and the usage `m++`(I think it is not suitable for *Function Programming*) :-)

Comment: My name is 汤书桃, @xzczd so it should be Mr.Tang:D

Comment: @ShutaoTang Oh, I think that besides some minorities, Chinese always put family name ahead. For your new question, you should notice that `InputForm` and `PrintPrecision` and `NumberForm` etc. Only control the display of the number, it doesn't influence `Precision` nor `Accuracy`. Nevertheless, calculate with `MachinePrecision` and control the display with `NumberForm`  etc. may be more close to what your text book has done, [significant arithmetic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60142/1871) is the secret recipe of _Mathematica_ anyway.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I am alaways having confusion about precison. But I think I will know it gradually by practicing and learning:)

Comment: BTW, you can replace `DeleteCases[Transpose@PadRight@rombergCalc[Exp, 6, {0, 1}, 13], 0, 2]` with `Flatten[rombergCalc[Exp, 6, {0, 1}, 13], {{2}, {1}}]`.I know that `Flatten[lst,{{2},{1}}]` can transpose the two-dimensional data that owns different length in the 2nd level. :-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Oh, I should have read the document of `Flatten` more carefully. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an old HW assignment. The code is not very functional at all. I even used `Break[]` in there (OMG!), but I get the same result as the table in the book shows.

I put them side-by-side with the magic of cut/paste:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code:

```
nmaRomberg[c_] := Module[{len = Length[c], r, k = 1, f, j, i},
   r = Table[0, {len}, {len}];
   r[[All, 1]] = c;
   Do[
    k++;
    f = 4^(k - 1);
    Do[r[[j, k]] = (f*r[[j + 1, k - 1]] - r[[j, k - 1]])/(f - 1), {j, 1, i - 1}],
    {i, len, 1, -1}
    ];
   r
   ];

nmaTrapz[func_, from_, to_, nStrips_] := Module[{nPoints = nStrips + 1, 
     h, x, int = 0, f},
  h = Abs[from - to]/nStrips;
  x = Range[from, to, h];
  Do[f = func[x[[i]]];
   int += If[i == 1 || i == nPoints, f, 2 f],
   {i, 1, nPoints}
   ];
  int*h/2
  ]
```

To use:

```
ClearAll[i, c];
fun = Exp; from = 0; to = 1; nStrips = 32; c = Table[0, {nStrips + 1}];
Do[
  c[[i]] = nmaTrapz[fun, from, to, 2^(i - 1)];
  If[2^(i - 1) > nStrips, Break[]],
  {i, 1, nStrips}];
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 16];
r = nmaRomberg[N[c]][[1 ;; 6, 1 ;; 3]]; (*pull out 3 columns from table*)
Insert[Transpose[r], Table[2^(i - 1), {i, Length[r]}], 1]; (*add n label*)
Grid[Transpose[%], Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

Comment: Reading this code is like looking at a picture of young Nasser and his pacifier. Thanks for sharing ;)

Comment: It is first for me to see the usage `SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 16]`. Thanks a lot!:-)

Comment: @belisarius it is not functional because the original HW [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/my_matlab_functions/depend/nma_romberg.m.txt) and [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/my_matlab_functions/depend/nma_romberg_test.m.txt) was in Matlab actually, and I just did now a quick 1:1 translation on the fly. (did not want to change many things so not to break it :)

Comment: @Nasser Oh! What a pity. I thought you were sharing the recording of your first baby steps with us :)

Comment: @Nasser, I have a confusion about the program written by my classmate in MATLAB. Namely, it took a hour when it run an time(OMG! too long,and the number of data is 1000). So is it normal?

Comment: @ShutaoTang one hr? No, it runs in Matlab just as fast as with Mathematica. I can't imagine why this would take one hr. May be your friend has a bug in the code. They can run the Matlab profiler on it to find where the slow down is.

Comment: @Nasser,it is another question/project, not my question I post.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a straightforward implementation of the formulas posted in the question.

```
Clear[t, s, c, r];
t[f_, {a_, b_}, n_] := (b - a)/(2 n) *
  ReplacePart[ConstantArray[2, n + 1], {1 -> 1, n + 1 -> 1}] . 
   (f /@ Rescale[Range[0, n], {0, n}, {a,b}])
s[f_, {a_, b_}, n_] := (4^1 t[f, {a, b}, 2 n] - t[f, {a, b}, n])/(4^1 - 1);
c[f_, {a_, b_}, n_] := (4^2 s[f, {a, b}, 2 n] - s[f, {a, b}, n])/(4^2 - 1);
r[f_, {a_, b_}, n_] := (4^3 c[f, {a, b}, 2 n] - c[f, {a, b}, n])/(4^3 - 1);
```

The OP's code suggests rather that what is desired is an implementation of Romberg quadrature via Richardson extrapolation of the trapezoidal rule.  It's pretty much the same thing, except that instead of using three functions `s`, `c`, `r` to perform the three extrapolation, one can do it iteratively in one function.

Here is a way to implement a Richardson extrapolation of the trapezoidal rule.  It adds the new coefficients and abscissas at each step to the previous arrays, so that function evaluations are not repeated.  It could be adapted to a recursive method that could stop when some convergence criteria were met.  It takes some steps to be efficient.  The coefficients of the function values `rx[n, m]` is a packed array of integers, and abscissas will be a packed array of reals, when using machine precision.  Not much checking is included, but for an industrial-strength integrator, use `NIntegrate`.  The test `listableQ` is an unnecessary enhancement: it assumes vectorization/`Listable` attributes of the integrand, if it passes a simple test; set `listableQ = False &`, if there's a problem, or cut it out of the code.  It saves time on functions like `Exp`.

```
ClearAll[rx, romberg];

rx[0, 0] = ConstantArray[1, 2];
rx[n_, 0] := ReplacePart[ConstantArray[2, 2^n + 1], {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1}];
rx[n_, m_] := Module[{rx0 = 2^(2 m - 1) rx[n, m - 1]},
   rx0[[;; 2^(n - 1) + 1]] -= rx[n - 1, m - 1];
   rx[n, m] = rx0];

rx[n_, m_, {a_, b_}, "abscissas"] := Fold[Join[#, Rest[#] - (b - a)/2^#2] &, 
  Developer`ToPackedArray@{a, b}, Range[1, n]];

rx[n_, m_, {a_, b_}, "scale"] := 
  Fold[#1*2/(4^#2 - 1) &, (b - a)/2^n/2, Range[m]];

listableQ[f_, x0_] := Quiet@MatchQ[f[{N@x0}], {_Real}];  (* weak test of Listable ? *)
romberg[f_, {a_, b_}, n_, m_, prec_: MachinePrecision] /; n >= m :=
  Module[{fvalues},
   If[listableQ[f, {x, a}],
    fvalues = f[rx[n, m, N[{a, b}, prec], "abscissas"]],
    fvalues = f /@ rx[n, m, N[{a, b}, prec], "abscissas"]];
   N[rx[n, m, {a, b}, "scale"], prec] rx[n, m].fvalues
   ];
```

Comparison:

```
N[E - 1, 20]
r[Exp, {0.``20, 1.`20}, 2^(7 - 3)]
romberg[Exp, {0, 1}, 7, 3, 20]
(*
  1.7182818284590452354
  1.718281828459045235     <-- r loses a little more precision than romberg
  1.7182818284590452354
*)
```

The following shows the equivalence between `romberg` and `t`, `s`, `c`, and `r`:

```
Block[{n = 3},
 t[f, {a, b}, 2^(n - 0)] == romberg[f, {a, b}, n, 0, Infinity] // Simplify // Print;
 s[f, {a, b}, 2^(n - 1)] == romberg[f, {a, b}, n, 1, Infinity] // Simplify // Print;
 c[f, {a, b}, 2^(n - 2)] == romberg[f, {a, b}, n, 2, Infinity] // Simplify // Print;
 r[f, {a, b}, 2^(n - 3)] == romberg[f, {a, b}, n, 3, Infinity] // Simplify // Print;
 ]
(*
  True
  True
  True
  True
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and dirty trick for obtaining only the top row of the Romberg triangle (which contains the (usually) most accurate estimates of the integral) by exploiting the connexion between Richardsonian extrapolation and the interpolating polynomial. First, we write a simple routine to generate the trapezoidal sums:

```
trapezoidal[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, n_Integer?Positive] := 
            Module[{fn = Function[x, f], h = b - a, m = 1, s},
                   s = (h/2) (fn[a] + fn[b]);
                   Table[If[k > 1, h /= 2; m *= 2;
                            s = s/2 + h Sum[fn[a + j h], {j, 1, m - 1, 2}]];
                         s, {k, n}]]
```

Let's use $\int_0^1 \exp(x)\,\mathrm dx$ as the example, just like in the OP:

```
n = 5;
ts = trapezoidal[N[Exp[x], 20], {x, 0, 1}, n]
   {1.8591409142295226177, 1.7539310924648253823, 1.7272219045575167293,
    1.7205185921643018614, 1.7188411285799943937}
```

Now, here's the Richardsonian magic:

```
pts = Transpose[{4^Range[0, 1 - n, -1], ts}];
rom = Table[InterpolatingPolynomial[Take[pts, k], 0], {k, n}]
   {1.8591409142295226177, 1.7188611518765929705, 1.7182826879247574588,
    1.7182818287945304232, 1.7182818284590783227}
```

Compare the relative errors:

```
correct = E - 1;
Round[-Log10[(ts - correct)/correct]]
   {1, 2, 2, 3, 3}

Round[-Log10[(rom - correct)/correct]]
   {1, 3, 6, 10, 14}
```