# Creating a summation table

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a list of values, for example {3,7,8,10}. Now I want to make a function that creates a table T in the following way:

$\begin{matrix}
3&7&8&10\\
&10&15&18\\
&&25&33\\
&&&58\\
\end{matrix}$

So we're adding up: 3+7=10, 7+8=15 etc.

Another complicating factor is that I want T[[2,2]]=10 (not T[[2,1]]); similarly, T[[4,4]]=58 etc.

BACKGROUND: In the end I am trying to make a function for Romberg Integration.

Comment: See here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9959/12 and here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65668/12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lst = {3, 7, 8, 10};

nl = NestList[MovingMap[Total, #, 1]&, lst, Length[lst] - 1]
```

> {{3,7,8,10},{10,15,18},{25,33},{58}}

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ PadLeft[nl, Automatic, ""]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  3 & 7 & 8 & 10 \\
>  \text{} & 10 & 15 & 18 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & 25 & 33 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 58 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, you can also use

```
Total /@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & (* or *)

Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Plus] &
```

in place of `MovingMap[Total, #, 1]&` above.

To get a 4X4 matrix, you can use `PadLeft` (with default padding 0):

```
nl2 = PadLeft[nl]
```

> {{3, 7, 8, 10}, {0, 10, 15, 18}, {0, 0, 25, 33}, {0, 0, 0, 58}}

```
nl2[[4, 4]]
```

> 58

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ nl2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  3 & 7 & 8 & 10 \\
>  0 & 10 & 15 & 18 \\
>  0 & 0 & 25 & 33 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 58 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thanks! That solves the first problem, but not the second: nl[[4,1]] is now 58 while it should be nl[[4,4]]

Comment: @GambitSquared, please see the updated version. In general, you can use your choice of `padding` in the third argument in `nl2= PadLeft[nl, Automatic, padding]` to fill the  lower triangular part ( `j < i`) of `nl2`.

Comment: Great! One more question: can I also (instead of Total) do some function on the two values? f[#1,#2]

Comment: @GambitSquared, does `NestList[f @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &, lst, 3]` give the desired result?