# How to set the Precision for a function?

Tags: programming, precision-and-accuracy

From this answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149890/19542)) to my question I need to add the `WorkingPrecision` option to `RandomVariate` for that particular `ProbabilityDistribution` not to experience what I guess is an overflow off some sort and return incorrect values.

Another option given by WRI was to use `Rationalize[ #, 0]&` on each of the parameter values to effectively give them infinite precision such that the calculations would not experience any precision anomalies.

Is there a way to set the precision on the function such that it does all its calculations at the prescribe precision?

I tried by setting `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision` as in this answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60291/19542)).

```
ClearAll[genParetoCDF]; 
genParetoCDF[μ_, ξ_, σ_, x_] := 
 Block[{$MinPrecision = 2 $MachinePrecision, $MaxPrecision = 2 $MachinePrecision},
  Piecewise[{
   {1 - (1 + ((x - μ)*ξ)/σ)^(-ξ^(-1)), 
     (x >= μ && ξ > 0) || (μ <= x <= μ - σ/ξ && ξ < 0)}, 
   {1 - E^(-((x - μ)/σ)), 
     x >= μ && ξ == 0}
  }]
 ]
```

However it still returns `MachinePrecision` values.

```
Precision@genParetoCDF[.2, .5 10^6, 100000, 1 10^6]
```

> ```
> MachinePrecision
> ```

When used with `RandomVariate` without `WorkingPrecision` it still results in negatives (from what I think is the overflow).

With

```
ClearAll[gpdDist];
gpdDist[μ_, ξ_, σ_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", genParetoCDF[μ, ξ, σ, x]}, {x, μ, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {{μ, ξ, σ} ∈ Reals, σ > 0}]
```

Then (Also curious as to why this does not generate some sort of overflow error)

```
Min@RandomVariate[dist, 1000000]
```

> ```
> -7.49163*10^6
> ```

Is it possible to set the precision on the function?  I still need to be able to use the function symbolically as well. For example,

```
Assuming[{ξ > 0, σ > 0, {ξ, μ, σ} ∈ Reals},
 Limit[genParetoCDF[ξ, μ, σ, x], x -> ∞]
 ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It yields machine precision because you feed it machine precision arguments. Machine precision is infectious: almost any calculation that has machine precision as input will have machine precision as output unless you do something that explicitly demands otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetPrecision[]` to set the initial precision of your arguments:

```
ClearAll[genParetoCDF];
genParetoCDF[μ0_, ξ0_, σ0_, x0_] := 
  Module[{μ, ξ, σ, x},
   {μ, ξ, σ, x} = SetPrecision[{μ0, ξ0, σ0, x0}, 2 $MachinePrecision];
   Block[{$MinPrecision = 2 $MachinePrecision, $MaxPrecision = 2 $MachinePrecision},
    Piecewise[
       {{1 - (1 + ((x - μ)*ξ)/σ)^(-ξ^(-1)),
         (x >= μ && ξ > 0) || (μ <= x <= μ - σ/ξ && ξ < 0)},
        {1 - E^(-((x - μ)/σ)), x >= μ && ξ == 0}}]
    ]];

genParetoCDF[.2, .5 10^6, 100000, 1 10^6]
Precision[%]
(*
  0.000030849421087619473139643876639982
  31.9092
*)
```

You might consider controlling the precision of the inputs to `gpdDist`, too:

```
gpdDist[μ_, ξ_, σ_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", genParetoCDF[μ, ξ, σ, x]},
  {x, SetPrecision[μ, 2*$MachinePrecision], ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {{μ, ξ, σ} ∈ Reals, σ > 0}];
```

Then I get results like this (no overflow, no variates outside domain):

```
dist = gpdDist[.5 10^6, .2, .1 10^6];

RandomVariate[dist, WorkingPrecision -> 2*$MachinePrecision]
(*  512877.53799123430547484091911214  *)

Min@RandomVariate[dist, 1000000, WorkingPrecision -> 2*$MachinePrecision]
(*  500000.01897993857486312711526885  *)
```

It also works symbolically (see caveat below about symbolic expressions and numerics):

```
Assuming[{ξ > 0, σ > 0, {ξ, μ, σ} ∈ Reals}, 
 Limit[genParetoCDF[ξ, μ, σ, x], x -> ∞]]
(*  Piecewise[{{1, μ >= 0}}, 0]  *)
```

You might want to consider issuing a warning if the input has a precision less than `2 $MachinePrecision`.  Using input less than the working precision should be considered poor practice, if not an error.  Further, once you have the symbolic CDF function, the symbol-variables in it will no longer have the precision control, since such control applies only to numbers and by extension can be applied only in numeric routines.  Code like `RandomVariate[dist]` will use machine precision inputs, and numeric error in this case will lead to bogus results.  If you want the symbolic `Piecewise` CDF expression to use in calculations, then you have to give input values for the symbols of sufficient precision.  (Actually, that would be my recommended practice in this case, as I currently understand it.  I would probably get rid of the `$MinPrecision`/`$MaxPrecision` stuff.  If you're trying to deal with unreliable users, then your code must catch any of their numeric input and check/fix its precision.  This is hard to do, if they are allowed to use `ReplaceAll` and other built-in functions, bypassing your code, on the symbolic CDF.)

Comment: This does get `genPareto` returning the requested precision.  However, it still suffers the overflow issue when used with `RandomVariate`, with `dist = gpdDist[.5 10^6, .2, .1 10^6]` for example. I can't use `?NumericQ` as that will prevent me from using the function symbolically.

Comment: @Edmund Note that my answer works symbolically and allows arbitrary argument precision to override the default. Can't help you with `RandomVariate`, though.

Comment: @Edmund That's because you don't set the precision of `gpdDIst` and you get the same issue mentioned in chat -- it uses machine precision when you give m.p. input, and therefore so does `dist` and `RandomVariate`.  The overflow/negative random variates has to do with rounding error, I suppose.  I get no such problems with high precision inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Write a generic function, and then define special cases that recognize machine number arguments. Translate those to the necessary precision, and then use your generic function.

```
 genParetoCDF[μ_, ξ_, σ_, x_] := 
   Piecewise[{{1 - (1 + ((x - μ)*ξ)/σ)^(-ξ^(-1)), (x >= μ && ξ > 0) || (μ <= 
        x <= μ - σ/ξ && ξ < 0)}, {1 - 
     E^(-((x - μ)/σ)), x >= μ && ξ == 0}}]

genParetoCDF[μ_, ξ_, σ_, x_] := 
 genParetoCDF[
   SetPrecision[μ, 2 $MachinePrecision], ξ, σ, x] /; 
MachineNumberQ[μ]

genParetoCDF[μ_, ξ_, σ_, x_] := 
 genParetoCDF[μ, 
   SetPrecision[ξ, 2 $MachinePrecision], σ, x] /; 
  MachineNumberQ[ξ]

genParetoCDF[μ_, ξ_, σ_, x_] := 
 genParetoCDF[μ, ξ, 
   SetPrecision[σ, 2 $MachinePrecision], x] /; 
  MachineNumberQ[σ]

genParetoCDF[μ_, ξ_, σ_, x_] := 
 genParetoCDF[μ, ξ, σ, 
   SetPrecision[x, 2 $MachinePrecision]] /; MachineNumberQ[x]

Precision[genParetoCDF[.2, .5 10^6, 100000, 1 10^6]]
(* 31.8819 *)
```